pytorch，pinn2 the loss is getting smaller,but the pictures are not match at -1
The function I try to solve the boundary value problem:
enter image description here
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

torch.manual_seed(123)


class MLP(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLP,self).__init__()
        self.net = torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Linear(1,32),
                torch.nn.Tanh(),
                torch.nn.Linear(32,32),
                torch.nn.Tanh(),
                torch.nn.Linear(32,32),
                torch.nn.Tanh(),
                torch.nn.Linear(32,1),                
                )
    def forward(self,x):
        return self.net(x)


def exact_solution(ep, t):
    return (1-torch.exp(-(t+1)/2/ep))/(1-np.exp(-1/ep))

def gradients(u,x,order =1):
    if order == 1:
        return torch.autograd.grad(u,x,grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u),
                                   create_graph=True,
                                   only_inputs=True
                                   )[0]
    else:
        return gradients(gradients(u,x),x,order = order-1)

pinn = MLP()


t_boundary1 = torch.tensor(0.).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)-1
t_boundary2 = torch.tensor(0.).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)+1# (1, 1)


t_physics = torch.linspace(-0.95,1,100).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)
t_physics0 = torch.linspace(-1,-0.95,60).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)
tt=torch.cat([t_physics,t_physics0],dim=0)
ep=1e-2
t_test = torch.linspace(-1,1,600).view(-1,1)
u_exact = exact_solution(ep, t_test)
optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(pinn.parameters(),lr=1e-3)
for i in range(15001):
    optimiser.zero_grad()
    
    
    
    u1 = pinn(t_boundary1)
    loss1 = (torch.squeeze(u1) - 0)**2
    u2 = pinn(t_boundary2)
    loss2 = (torch.squeeze(u2) - 1)**2
    
    
    
    u = pinn(tt)
    dudt =gradients(u,tt,1)
    d2udt2 =gradients(u,tt,2)
    loss3 = torch.mean((ep*d2udt2 +1/2*dudt)**2)
    
    loss = loss1 + loss2 + loss3
    loss.backward()
    
    optimiser.step()
    
    if i%3000==0:
        print(i,loss1,loss2,loss3)
u = pinn(t_test).detach()
        
plt.plot(t_test[:,0], u_exact[:,0], label="Exact solution", color="tab:grey", alpha=0.6)
plt.plot(t_test[:,0], u[:,0], label="PINN solution", color="tab:green")
plt.title(f"Training step {i}")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('pinnbvpsolution0.01.png')
plt.show()    
    
    
plt.plot(t_test[:,0], u_exact[:,0]-u[:,0], label="Error", color="tab:grey", alpha=0.6)
plt.title(f"Training step {i}")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('pinnbvperror0.01.png')

plt.show()


i can solve this problem when ep=0.01 but when ep=0.001 the pictures are not match
I think the problem is gradient explode when ep =0.001 because the function resemble a line at -1 and the gradient is very big , but i don't know how to solve this problem.
